# Upload new APNS certificate to GCM

Tags: ios, google-cloud-messaging, certificate, apple-push-notifications

We have an app for iOS and Android that uses GCM. I'm trying to upload a new production APNS certificate to GCM but I can't because Google is moving GCM to Firebase.

How do I do that? Here's a screenshot of the Google Developer Products. There's no GCM now.

[image: Google Developer Products screenshot]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest that you move to Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM). If you go to the [Firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com) you will be able to create a new Firebase project or import an existing Google project. Once you are in your Firebase project you will be able to connect your iOS and Android apps. You can then upload your APNs cert there.

See the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client#set_up_the_sdk) for more details on connecting iOS apps and uploading APNs cert to Firebase.

Comment: OK, but in that case, would we have to make changes on the backend or on the apps? It is not clear to me that the transition is transparent.

Comment: We moved to Firebase. We have to make changes on the server, but the clients work fine. Thanks!