# Access the old Google cloud message

Tags: google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I know FCM is the new GCM. However, can the old GCM configuration still be accessed? I am using Cordova and the original plugin doesn't seem to support FCM at the moment. GCM used to work for me but I haven't been fiddling with it for a while and I can hardly find where to set it up and many documentations seem to lead to the newer FCM.

Comment: Which specific *configurations* are you looking for?

Comment: The configuration to get it running. Such as sender key. I am more familiar with the iOS platform and so I am kind of confused as to what I need to get it running. It was working fine before. But now messages is no longer receiving. So I need to take a look if I set it correctly.

Comment: For iOS, what you usually need to set are the APNS certificates. The advised way is to *import* your GCM project to the Firebase Console, where you'll be able to view these configuration settings.

Comment: See this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37439013/4625829). It might help.

Comment: Yeah but I would like to see if I can do without the newer Firebase messaging. So I don't know why you edit it to tag the firebase-cloud-messaging.

Comment: Added it since it is a related tag. :)

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I meant I am more familiar with iOS, but not so familiar with Android. So I am kind of confused as to what I need to get Android GCM running.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141926/discussion-between-al-and-huggie).