# Is there still a way to upload ios push certificate for GCM?

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

I know the service is shutting down this April,  and I have a plan to migrate to Firebase early next year (late January).  But my ios certificates need to be replaced now.

I had saved a link to the web page for uploading the certificates but now it just points to Firebase.

Does anyone know how I can upload my ios Push Certificates?  Again I know the service is shutting down "As early as April 11 2019",  but that still 4 months away.

Comment: Based on [SO 37439013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37439013/upload-new-apns-certificate-to-gcm) and [SO 45855559](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45855559/update-new-apns-certificate-to-gcm), it doesn't look like you can still upload to GCM. It is strongly suggested to migrate to FCM. You can refer to this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client#set_up_the_sdk) for more details on connecting iOS apps and uploading APNs cert to Firebase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the posts in Jacque's comments,  it does not seem like anyone has found a way to do this.  While it does seem like it should be supported until April 11 2019, it turns out it's not really as difficult as I thought.  I assumed I had to update my server code, android code and ios code all at the sametime, but that is not the case.

The answer to the third FAQ [here](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/faq) says this:

> How long do I have to migrate to FCM?
>
> We will turn off most GCM services in April 2019, so you should plan to have most of your services migrated by then.
>
> **Note that client SDKs and GCM tokens will continue to work indefinitely.** However, you won't be able to target the latest version
>   of Google Play Services in your Android app unless you migrate to FCM.

So this means that the server and each client can be updated separately and really only the server code needs to be update by April,  the clients can lag behind and potentially remain unchanged.

On the server side, all that is required is to change the server endpoints as the FCM Rest API supports the existing GCM Rest API.

Note: You still have to import the GCM project into FCM and add the ios certificates or key.